# how to trigger an AJAX request before or after an onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this form that when submitted I need it to trigger my ajax request, but the thing is that it has an onsubmit function within it and does my ajax request is not being triggered. So, I am wondering if there is a chance for me to do this. Also, I cannot do anything to the onsubmit and I cannot edit/delete it so that is why I added my own different onclick function. Code below:

**my own js with ajax:**

```
$(document).on('click','#Notes_subpanel_save_button',function (){
    var assigned_id = $("#assigned_user_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php?entryPoint=getsupportticket",
        data: {notification_update: "update", assigned_id: assigned_id, ticket_record: QueryString.record},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML of the button:**

```
<input title="Save" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('form_SubpanelQuickCreate_Notes'); disableOnUnloadEditView(); _form.action.value='Save';if(check_form('form_SubpanelQuickCreate_Notes'))return SUGAR.subpanelUtils.inlineSave(_form.id, 'Notes_subpanel_save_button');return false;" type="submit" name="Notes_subpanel_save_button" id="Notes_subpanel_save_button" value="Save">
```

Comment: When you click on save button page is refresh?

Comment: @NikhilVaghla nope it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
beforeSend: function () {
 // YOUR CODE
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use  ajaxStart and  ajaxStop

```
$(".button").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).button("disable");
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).button("enable");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$('#Notes_subpanel_save_button'). on('click',  function()  {
  // make ajax call
}) ;
```